# check if there is a file name inside an array of addresses

Tags: javascript

I have an array of addresses (all mp3 files) and I want to search the array via a function like this:

```
const Voices = [

    "https://example.com/english/advanced/intermediate/lesson_1_1/guides/translate/i%20sent.mp3",
  "https://example.com/english/sources/starter/lesson_1_1/track/translate/i%20sent_1.mp3",
  "https://example.com/english/sources/intermediate/go/vira/vox/i%20sent_2.mp3"

];

fileExist(Voices, "i_m%20sent"); // return false
fileExist(Voices, "i%20sent"); // return true
```

I'm not able to find a solution to do this please help...

Comment: Fairly easy with `Array.prototype.find` and a usage of `includes` or `indexOf`.  What have you tried?

Comment: Please show any attempt that you have made to solve this issue yourself.  You are expected to have made an attempt that we can then help you debug.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users  Also review [ask]

Answer (score 2):

There are 100 ways to do this. [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is probably the easiest way, but this is the most straight-forward.

```js
const Voices = [
  "https://example.com/english/advanced/intermediate/lesson_1_1/guides/translate/i%20sent.mp3",
  "https://example.com/english/sources/starter/lesson_1_1/track/translate/i%20sent_1.mp3",
  "https://example.com/english/sources/intermediate/go/vira/vox/i%20sent_2.mp3"
];

console.log(fileExist(Voices, "i_m%20sent")); // return false
console.log(fileExist(Voices, "i%20sent")); // return true

function fileExist(haystack, needle){
  for(let i=0; i<haystack.length; i++){
    let basename = haystack[i].split("/").pop()
    basename = basename.substring(0, basename.length-4);
    if(needle === basename) return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use .some method of array.

```js
const Voices = [
"https://example.com/english/advanced/intermediate/lesson_1_1/guides/translate/i%20sent.mp3",
  "https://example.com/english/sources/starter/lesson_1_1/track/translate/i%20sent_1.mp3",
  "https://example.com/english/sources/intermediate/go/vira/vox/i%20sent_2.mp3"
];


function fileExist(array,str){
  return array.some(obj => obj.includes(str));
}

console.log(fileExist(Voices, "i_m%20sent")); // return false
console.log(fileExist(Voices, "i%20sent"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to break the problem down into simpler terms. You are not just trying to find a file name in a list of URLs. You are trying to find a Substring in a list of Strings.

So you need to check if each string contains a smaller string.

```
const fileExist = (a, string) => {
    for (let i in a) {
        if(a[ i ].includes(string)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

(So perhaps a better name for this function could be arrayOfStringsContainsSubstring)